# Android Fragment Navigation and updating DrawerLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity that contains a DrawerLayout.
I have defined Fragments for that DrawerLayout in separate classes.
I am trying to add a button inside a Fragment that should navigate to another Fragment.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyActivity()).commit();
```

It works, but the DrawerLayout is not updated.  The title needs to be updated to match the new Fragment, and when the Drawer is opened, the old Fragment is still selected.

What is the proper way to navigate from Fragment to Fragment?

Comment: Your `MyActivity` extends Fragment?

Comment: Yes, MyActivity extends Fragment

Comment: It's very strange to call class extending Fragment like that. It can confuse other people. But closer to the question: have you followed this tutorial http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html ? take a look on a function `selectItem` there, it has everything you need.

Comment: Yes, that is what my code is based off of.  However, for a button in a Fragment, there is no way to access the DrawerList or the DrawerLayout (to update the list and title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrode the Fragment class's onAttach in order to access the root activity.
By doing it this way, I was able to store the callback interface in the Fragment as a field.

In MyActivity.java (A Fragment)

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        fragmentNavigation = (IFragmentNavigation) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement IFragmentNavigation");
    }
}
```